# Find coefficient of $x^{20}$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

Find the coefficient of $x^{70}$ in the expansion

> $$(x-1)(x^2-2)(x^3-3)(x^4-4)\cdots (x^{12}-12)$$

$\mathcal {\text {Now I have solved this question}}$. What I did was I noticed that the highest power that can be formed in this expansion  would be $78$ . Hence I need to find the sum of Distinct numbers that on addition would form $8$ and I have to multiply them among themselves .
Hence the answer would be simply

$$(-8) + [(-1)(-7) + (-2)(-6) + (-3)(-5)] + [(-1)(-3)(-4) + (-1)(-2)(-5)]  = 4$$

> $\mathcal {\text {But what if something like coefficient of $x^{20}$ would have been asked}}$.

Because the way I used would expend a lot of time to solve it.  I want to know if there are any standard methods to solve it.

Comment: the solution should be $4$

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner Would you please explain how you got coefficient 
of  $x^{20}$ so fast. I have already found the coefficient of $x^{70}$. I need coefficient 
of  $x^{20}$

Comment: @Masacroso I need coefficient of $x^{20}$

Comment: @Masacroso the OP explains that he solved the 70 problem and is simply asking whether there would be an easier method than his

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806421/fastest-way-to-find-integer-coefficients-for-an-integer-valued-polynomial) is suspiciously answered ... nothing better than $a_{20}=\frac{p^{(20)}(0)}{20!}$ comes to my mind.

Comment: @rytbase I don't know what Vandermonde's matrix nor did I understand what you mean to say. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Given $p(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{78}a_nx^n$ taking $20$-th derivative of that polynomial at $x=0$, which is $p^{(20)}(0)$, we can find the coefficient of $x^{20}$ by $a_{20}=\frac{p^{(20)}(0)}{20!}$. Taking a derivative $20$ times is still not a quick operation, unless [you can find any shortcuts](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69476/fast-evaluation-of-polynomials).

Comment: @rytbase using the derivative method we can find nearly all coefficients of any polynomial but I want a solution less dependent on calculus and derivative thing. There must be some way using binomial coefficients or some other part except for a higher calculus thing

Comment: Another not so easy (at least I don't see it), but with less calculus, is [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), since you have all the roots or they are easy to see.

Comment: I thought this was the kind of thing one did by Mathematica: +1152600

Comment: @almagest  Is the question this much complicated that I am not getting any binomial coefficients method or any polynomial method to solve it without using calculators or computer software.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dividing by $x^{78}$ and substituting $x\mapsto\frac1x$ shows that
$$
\left[x^{70}\right]\prod_{k=1}^{12}\left(x^k-k\right)=\left[x^8\right]\prod_{k=1}^{12}\left(1-kx^k\right)
$$
and
$$
\left[x^{20}\right]\prod_{k=1}^{12}\left(x^k-k\right)=\left[x^{58}\right]\prod_{k=1}^{12}\left(1-kx^k\right)
$$
It is not too difficult to derive the recursion
$$
\overbrace{\left[x^m\right]\prod_{k=1}^{n\vphantom{-1}}\left(1-kx^k\right)}^{a(n,m)}
=\overbrace{\left[x^m\right]\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1-kx^k\right)}^{a(n-1,m)}
-n\,\overbrace{\left[x^{m-n}\right]\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1-kx^k\right)}^{a(n-1,m-n)}
$$
So if we define
$$
a(n,m)=\left\{\begin{array}{}
0&\text{if $m\lt0$ or $m\gt\frac{n(n+1)}2$}\\
1&\text{if $m=0$}\\
a(n-1,m)-n\,a(n-1,m-n)&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
$$
then
$$
a(12,8)=4
$$
and
$$
a(12,58)=1152600
$$
This requires less work than computing $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{12}\left(x^k-k\right)$, but it still is not simple.

Although, when doing this by hand, the table of $a(n,m)$ gets big, it is no more difficult than computing Pascal's Triangle. For example, computing $a(12,58)$ required only $75$ values to be computed; that is less than computing $12$ rows of Pascal's Triangle.

---

**Mathematica Code**

`a[n_,m_]:=If[m==0,1,If[m<0||m>n(n+1)/2,0,a[n,m]=a[n-1,m]-n a[n-1,m-n]]]`

Answer (score 4):

Let's formalize you process, which is valid.  Your polynomial is
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{12} (x^k -k)
$$

Now define $\mathbb B[12]$ the space of boolean vectors of length $12$.  (that is the set sequences of $0$ or $1$ of length $12$).

The expansion is

$$
\sum_{b\in\mathbb B[12]} \prod_{k=1}^{12} (b_k x^k) + (1-b_k)(-k)
$$

You now want to select the terms such that
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{12} (b_k x^k) + (1-b_k)(-k) = c x^{20}
$$

for some $c \in \mathbb R$.  Note that if $b_k = 1$, then $(1-b_k)(-k)$ is $0$.  So let's ignore that term for now.  You're looking for the $b \in \mathbb B[12]$ such that
$$
\prod_{\substack{k\in\{1..12\}\\b_k \ne 0}} b_k x^k = x^{20}.
$$

Which is
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{12} x^{b_k \cdot k} = x^{20}.
$$

Since $x^{a} \cdot x^{b} = x^{a+b}$, you can translate that equation on the coefficients.

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{12} b_k k = 20
$$

This is a rather recursive problem.  The number of solutions $b \in \mathbb B[12]$ is the number of solutions $b \in \mathbb B[11]$ that sums to $20$ (if $b_{12} = 0$) plus the number of solutions $b \in \mathbb B[11]$ that sums to $20-12 = 8$ (if $b_{12} = 1$).

\begin{align}
\left\{b \in \mathbb B[12]: \sum_{k=1}^{12} b_k k = 20 \right\}
&= \left\{[b,0] : b \in \mathbb B[11] \text{ and } \sum_{k=1}^{11} b_k k = 20 \right\} \\
&\cup \left\{[b,1] : b \in \mathbb B[11] \text{ and } \sum_{k=1}^{11} b_k k = 8 \right\}
\end{align}

I'll let you search a solution for the recursion if it exists (I don't have the time sorry, I feel the solution cannot be simply written anyway).

Note that for $b \in \mathbb B[12]$ that is a solution, its associated coefficient is
$$\prod_{\substack{k\in\{1..12\}\\b_k \ne 1}} (-k).$$

Hence sum for each $b \in \mathbb B[12]$ that is a solution to the above recursion, their associated coefficients to your final answer.

Comment: I greatly appreciate the way you answered the question but I really apologize because I don't pretty much have any idea about the Boolean space vector cause I haven't been taught anything like that until now. But I have upvoted  the answer though because you took out your precious time to answer the question.   As for the name suggests I think it is related to vectors which I haven't studied yet,  so really sorry for the trouble caused

Comment: Well i'm not doing an advanced usage.  In this case it's just a convenient way of cobbling 12 values together.  Think of an array of twelves values $b_1$, ..., $b_12$, each allowed to have value $0$ ("false") or $1$ ("true").  Hence $\mathbb B[1] = \{[b_0 = 0], [b_0 = 1]\}$ and $\mathbb B[2] = \{[b_0 = 0, b_1 = 0], [b_0 = 0, b_1 = 1], [b_0 = 1, b_1 = 0], [b_0 = 1, b_1 = 1]\}$ and so on.  Ultimately you write a vector as something like $[0, 1, 1, 0]$ where the value of $b_i$ is the $i$th value in the array.

Answer (score 1):

And Wolfy says the answer is

$$
x^{78} - x^{77} - 2 x^{76} - x^{75} - x^{74} + 5 x^{73} + x^{72} + 13 x^{71} + 4 x^{70} + 2 x^{68} - 8 x^{67} - 61 x^{66} - 18 x^{65} + 14 x^{64} - 181 x^{63} - 19 x^{62} - 45 x^{61} + 228 x^{60} + 111 x^{59} + 281 x^{58} + 683 x^{57} + 1248 x^{56} + 486 x^{55} + 379 x^{54} - 1668 x^{53} - 384 x^{52} + 404 x^{51} - 7810 x^{50} - 6207 x^{49} - 9633 x^{48} - 3231 x^{47} - 6517 x^{46} + 14633 x^{45} + 416 x^{44} + 7701 x^{43} + 51725 x^{42} + 61060 x^{41} + 31028 x^{40} + 99864 x^{39} + 27934 x^{38} - 20684 x^{37} - 121316 x^{36} - 158122 x^{35} - 33316 x^{34} - 434638 x^{33} - 232730 x^{32} - 472780 x^{31} - 363980 x^{30} - 546300 x^{29} + 595776 x^{28} + 371604 x^{27} + 2874060 x^{26} + 1092936 x^{25} - 85176 x^{24} + 1736472 x^{23} + 999408 x^{22} + 1959960 x^{21} + 1152600 x^{20} + 611616 x^{19} - 2386848 x^{18} - 7381296 x^{17} - 14072832 x^{16} - 22188528 x^{15} - 4414320 x^{14} + 40194720 x^{13} - 9756000 x^{12} + 1978560 x^{11} - 2756160 x^{10} - 380160 x^{9} - 7413120 x^{8} + 39346560 x^{7} - 3991680 x^{6} + 103783680 x^{5} + 39916800 x^{4} + 79833600 x^{3} - 239500800 x^{2} - 479001600 x + 479001600
$$

so robjohn is correct.

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$$
P(x,n) = \prod\limits_{1\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( {x^{\,k}  - k} \right)} 
  = \left. {{\partial  \over {\partial y}}\prod\limits_{1\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( {x^{\,k}  - y^{\,k} } \right)\;} } \right|_{\,y\, = \,1} 
$$

and
$$
\eqalign{
  & P(x,y,n) = \prod\limits_{1\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( {x^{\,k}  - y^{\,k} } \right)\;}
  = x^{\,n\left( {n + 1} \right)/2} \prod\limits_{1\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( {1 - \left( {{y \over x}} \right)^{\,k} } \right)\;}  =   \cr 
  &  = x^{\,n\left( {n + 1} \right)/2} \prod\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {\left( {1 - {y \over x}\left( {{y \over x}} \right)^{\,k} } \right)\;}
  = x^{\,n\left( {n + 1} \right)/2} \left( {{y \over x};\;{y \over x}} \right)_{\,n}  \cr} 
$$
where $\left( {a;\;z} \right)_{\,q} $ denotes the [q-Pochhammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol) .

It is known that, in terms of *q-Binomial* coefficents $\left( \matrix{   m \cr    k \cr}  \right)_{\,q} $
the series expansion of the $P(x,y,n)$ can be written as
$$
\eqalign{
  & P(x,y,n) = x^{\,n\left( {n + 1} \right)/2} \left( {{y \over x};\;{y \over x}} \right)_{\,n}  =   \cr 
  &  = x^{\,\left( {\scriptstyle n + 1 \atop 
  \scriptstyle 2}  \right)} \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,n} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)_{\,y/x} \left( {{y \over x}} \right)^{\,j} \left( {{y \over x}} \right)^{\,\left( {\scriptstyle n \atop 
  \scriptstyle 2}  \right)} }   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,n} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)_{\,y/x} y^{\,\left( {\scriptstyle n \atop 
  \scriptstyle 2}  \right) + j} x^{\,n - j} }  \cr} 
$$

But the derivative of the q-Binomial is not easily expressible.

An alternative way is to rewrite $P(x,y,n)$ as 
$$
\eqalign{
  & P(x,y,n) = \prod\limits_{1\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( {x^{\,k}  - y^{\,k} } \right)\;}
  = y^{\,n\left( {n + 1} \right)/2} \prod\limits_{1\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( {\left( {{x \over y}} \right)^{\,k}  - 1} \right)\;}  =   \cr 
  &  = y^{\,n\left( {n + 1} \right)/2} Q(x/y,n) \cr} 
$$
and in turn, express $Q(z,n)$ as product of roots of unity
$$
\eqalign{
  & Q(z,n) = \prod\limits_{1\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( {z^{\,k}  - 1} \right)\;}
  = \prod\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {\prod\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,k - 1} {\left( {z - e^{\,i\;\,\left( {j/\left( {k + 1} \right)} \right)\,2\pi } } \right)} \;}  =   \cr 
  &  = \prod\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {\left( {z - \omega _{\,n,\,j,\,k} } \right)\;}
  = \prod\limits_{0\, \le \,l\, \le \,h - 1} {\left( {\,z - s_{\,l} } \right)}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,q\, \le \,h} {c_{\,h,\,h - q} \,z^{\,q} } \quad \left| {\;h
  = \left( \matrix{ {n+1} \cr   2 \cr}  \right)} \right. \cr} 
$$
The coefficients $c_{\,h,\,h - q}$ are given by the [OEIS sequence A231599](http://oeis.org/A231599).
There is a recurrence indicated therein, that is (putting the indices in bracket for better readability)
$$c(n,k) = c(n-1, k) - c(n-1, n*(n-1)/2-k)*(-1)^n \quad |\; n > 1$$

Another interesting recurrence is provided [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2673252)

The $c_{\,h,\,h - q}$ coefficients could also be computed by resorting to *Vieta's formulas*.
But in doing that we shall be careful to note that the fraction $j/(k+1)$ when reduced will provide repeated values,
 and consequently repeated are the $s_l$.
$$
\eqalign{
  & \prod\limits_{0\, \le \,l\, \le \,h - 1} {\left( {\,z - s_{\,l} } \right)}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,h} {c_{\,h,\,h - q} \,z^{\,q} } \quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad c_{\,h,\,m}  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,m} \sum\limits_{\,\left\{ {k_{\,0} \,,\,k_{\,1} \,,\, \cdots \,,\,k_{\,m - 1} } \right\}\,\,
 \subset \;\left\{ {0\,,\,1\,,\, \cdots \,,\,h - 1} \right\}\;\;} {\prod\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,m - 1} {s_{\,k_{\,j} } } }  \cr} 
$$
After which , going back to $P(x,y,n)$ and derive wrt $y$ is quite straight.

Otherwise, it is possible to start directly from $P(x,n)$, rewritten as
$$
\eqalign{
  & P(x,n) = \prod\limits_{1\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( {x^{\,k}  - k} \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \prod\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {\;\prod\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,k - 1} 
 {\left( {x - \left( {k + 1} \right)^{\,1/\left( {k + 1} \right)} e^{\,i\;\,\left( {j/\left( {k + 1} \right)} \right)\,2\pi } } \right)} \;}  \cr} 
$$
and applying *Vieta's formulas* as above.

Although algebraically interesting, I am however concious that this approach is **not computationally viable** for large $n$.